# PHP globals in WordPress not returning expected value

Tags: php, wordpress, upload

I am working on a 2 part form to allow users to create posts on WordPress.

The first part takes in the post title, content, and link, then creates the post from that data using AJAX. When the post is created using `wp_insert_post()` the post ID is returned.

```
function makeblog_page2form (){

    global $make_post_id;

    if( check_admin_referer('page2form_submit','page2form_subform') ){

        // more code

        $make_post_id = wp_insert_post( $post );


        exit;

    } else{
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/submission-error/' ) );
        exit;
    }

}
```

The second part takes an image and uploads it the WordPress gallery and then attaches the image to the post to be it's featured image. For the image submission I am using [Frontend Uploader](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/frontend-uploader/), and using the included `add_action('fu_after_upload', callback_function)` with this plugin.

I am running into issues when I try to use the `$make_post_id` global within the `add_action()` to attach the image, nothing is returned.

```
add_action( 'fu_after_upload', function( $attachment_ids ) { 

    global $make_post_id;
    var_dump($make_post_id); // no return value

} );
```

Both of these are within the same file.php.

If this isn't clear enough let me know. Thanks.

Comment: does it output anything before calling `add_action()` ?

Comment: Yes, within the function it does create the post and return the correct post ID. Trying to pass that ID to another scope within the same PHP file is problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Try passing this variable to the anonymous function scope:</s>

```
global $make_post_id;
add_action( 'fu_after_upload', function( $attachment_ids ) use ($make_post_id){
    var_dump($make_post_id);
});
```

Global variables does not preserve values between separate request, so you have either return post ID form first call and pass it alongside uploaded files or store and access it in `$_SESSION` array.

Comment: And if you move `var_dump()` between `global ...` and `add_action` ?

Comment: `NULL` and `NULL`, which would mean its not being stored correctly after post creation.

Comment: The post ID is being assigned to the variable in `makeblog_page2form` scope, but it's not storing after leaving that scope. Any ideas?

Comment: Just reread your question, are you submitting and creating post in one ajax request, and the uploading image, after ajax return post id ?

Comment: Yes except I am not returning the post id using AJAX. I am just trying to use PHP globals to retrieve the id.

Comment: It does not work that way. You have to return this ID to javascript and pass it with uploaded files, or store it in the `$SESSION` array. Global variables are alive only for one request.

Comment: Wonderful, although not exactly what I was hoping for, but keeps me going. Thank you very much.